# Output binding in an ontology

Tags: semantics, ontology, protege

I am trying to complete the following ontology using Protege OWL-S Editor:

[image: ontology]

At the end of the if-else branch (where the branch merges), I would like to use a variable (like an output variable) so that I could use it to process with further Performs. I am unable to use the output of the branch since protege only allows me to choose either TheParentPerforms or the first st:subtractTenProcess under Start block.

How can I create a variable to use it for the following process?